# I can't save the email ID of the Facebook user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, oauth, facebook-social-plugins

I am using following code to allow my visitors to join my blog via Facebook. Users can log in with it successfully, but the problem is WordPress is not storing the email id. May be there is a silly mistake but I am not getting it.

**function.php**

```
// Facebook Login Button

require_once("inc/facebookoauth.php");
class Facebook_Login_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("facebook_login_widget", "Facebook Login", array("description" => __("Display a Facebook Login Button")));
    }

    public function form( $instance )
    {
        // Check values
        if($instance)
        {
            $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $app_key = $instance['app_key'];
            $app_secret = $instance['app_secret'];
        }
        else
        {
            $title = '';
            $app_key = '';
            $app_secret = '';
        }
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title', 'facebook_login_widget'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_key'); ?>"><?php _e('App ID:', 'facebook_login_widget'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_key'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('app_key'); ?>" value="<?php echo $app_key; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_secret'); ?>"><?php _e('App Secret:', 'facebook_login_widget'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_secret'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('app_secret'); ?>" value="<?php echo $app_secret; ?>" />
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance )
    {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['app_key'] = strip_tags($new_instance['app_key']);
        $instance['app_secret'] = strip_tags($new_instance['app_secret']);

        update_option("facebook_app_id", $new_instance['app_key']);
        update_option("facebook_app_secret", $new_instance['app_secret']);

        return $instance;
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance )
    {
        extract($args);

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        echo $before_widget;

        if($title)
        {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title ;
        }

        if(is_user_logged_in())
        {
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout"><input type="button" value="Logout" /></a>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=facebook_oauth_redirect'; ?>"><input type="button" value="Login Using Facebook" /></a>
            <?php
        }

        echo $after_widget;
    }
}
register_widget("Facebook_Login_Widget");
```

**inc/facebookauth.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

function facebook_oauth_redirect()
{
    global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
    require_once("../wp-load.php");
    //construct URL and redirect
    $app_id = get_option("facebook_app_id");
    $redirect_url = get_site_url() . "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=facebook_oauth_callback";
    $permission = "email,name";

    $final_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . urlencode($app_id) . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url) . "&permission=" . $permission;

    header("Location: " . $final_url); 
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_facebook_oauth_redirect", "facebook_oauth_redirect");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_oauth_redirect", "facebook_oauth_redirect");

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function facebook_oauth_callback()
{
    global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
    require_once("../wp-load.php");

    if(isset($_GET["code"]))
    {   
        $token_and_expire = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . get_option("facebook_app_id") . "&redirect_uri=". get_site_url() . "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=facebook_oauth_callback" . "&client_secret=" . get_option("facebook_app_secret") . "&code=" . $_GET["code"]);

        parse_str($token_and_expire, $_token_and_expire_array);


        if(isset($_token_and_expire_array["access_token"]))
        {   
            $access_token = $_token_and_expire_array["access_token"];
            $user_information = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $access_token . "&fields=email,name");
            $user_information_array = json_decode($user_information, true);

            $email = $user_information_array["email"];
            $name = $user_information_array["name"];
            if(username_exists($name))
            {
                $user_id = username_exists($name);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
                update_user_meta($user_id, "facebook_access_token", $access_token);
                header('Location: ' . get_site_url());
            }
            else
            {
                //create a new account and then login
                wp_create_user($name, generateRandomString(), $email);
                $user_id = username_exists($name);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
                update_user_meta($user_id, "facebook_access_token", $access_token);
                header('Location: ' . get_site_url());
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            header("Location: " . get_site_url());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: " . get_site_url());
    }

    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_facebook_oauth_callback", "facebook_oauth_callback");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_oauth_callback", "facebook_oauth_callback");
```

I tried adding $email in  `update_user_meta($user_id, "facebook_access_token", $access_token);` but its also not working.

Comment: The login URL you are creating is wrong. The name of the parameter for the permissions to ask for is not `permission`.

Comment: Then what should i do? can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change This**

```
 $final_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . urlencode($app_id) . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url) . "&permission=" . $permission;
```

**To**

```
$final_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . urlencode($app_id) . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url) . "&scope=" . $permission;
```

CBroe is right,
You have to use `&scope=` to ask for extra permissions.
I hope this will help you